# Ping to/from KVM QEMU VM running in another network namespace

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, network-namespace

I cannot ping to the default network namespace from a KVM QEMU VM running in a separate network namespace.

Here is my setup:

```
ip netns add test-ns

# Creating veth
ip link add if-in-ns type veth peer name if-notin-ns
# Default namespace
ip link addr add 10.21.0.10/24 dev if-notin-ns
ip link set dev if-notin-ns up
# Test-ns namespace
ip link set dev if-in-ns netns test-ns
ip netns exec test-ns ip addr add 10.21.0.20/24 dev if-in-ns
ip netns exec test-ns ip link set dev if-in-ns up

# Creating a tap device in the namespace
ip netns exec test-ns ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
ip netns exec test-ns ip addr add 10.0.2.2/24 dev tap0
ip netns exec test-ns ip link set dev tap0 up

# Create route to 10.0.2.0/24 if default namespace:
ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev if-notin-ns

# Run VM
ip netns exec test-ns qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=img.qcow2,format=qcow2,media=disk -accel kvm -cpu host -m 2G -netdev tap,id=vm0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vm0,mac=52:54:77:6a:cc:02
```

And these are the results:

```
# In default namespace:
ping 10.21.0.20 # Works
ping 10.0.2.2 # Works
ping 10.0.2.3 # Doesn't work

# In test-ns namespace:
ping 10.21.0.10 # Works
ping 10.0.2.3 # Works

# Inside the image:
ping 10.0.2.2 # Works
ping 10.21.0.20 # Works
ping 10.21.0.10 # Doesn't work
```

So the VM can ping dev *if-in-ns* and dev *if-in-ns* can ping its peer *if-notin-ns*. I thought this means the VM should be able to ping dev *if-notin-ns* as well, but it can't. What am I misunderstanding?

Edit: Comment to Salim Aljayousi answer:

The namespace test-ns already has a route to reach the default namespace via the dev *if-in-ns*:

```
ip netns exec test-ns ip route
10.0.2.0/24 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.2 
10.21.0.0/24 dev if-in-ns proto kernel scope link src 10.21.0.20
```

If I remove that one and add the one you suggest:

```
ip netns exec ns ip route del 10.21.0.0/24 dev if-in-ns
ip netns exec ns ip route add 10.21.0.0/24 dev tap0
```

Then within the VM I get:

````
ping 10.21.0.10
From 10.0.2.2 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.21.0.10) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can add a route in the test-ns namespace to reach the default namespace via the tap interface

```
ip netns exec test-ns ip route add 10.21.0.0/24 dev tap0
```

This should allow the VM to ping devices in the default namespace.

Note that you may also need to enable IP forwarding on the host system to allow packets to be forwarded between namespaces.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: I answered you in the main question, because the formatting there is nicer, I hope that's fine.